# Como colocar vários números em uma var

Tags: javascript

```
var input = require('fs').readFileSync('/dev/stdin', 'utf8');
var lines = input.split('\n');

var i, p;

console.log(a);
p = 0;

{
    for(i = 1; i <= 6; i = i + 1);

    if(x > 0.0){
        p = p + 1;
    }
    console.log(p + ' valores positivos');
}
```

Tenho que usar este código para ler 6 números (lines[0] ate lines[5]) e mostrar quantos são positivos, porem não sei como criar uma var que leia todas as linhas como números, tentei usar var x = [lines[0], lines[1], ..., lines[5]]; Porem lê como string e não consigo usar x.split(","); Como eu devo fazer?
Input padrão:

7;
-5;
6;
-3.4;
4.6;
12;

Answer (score 0):

Tente o seguinte script:

```
var p = 0;
var lines = input.split(";")

for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    if(parseFloat(lines[i]) > 0.0){
         p = p + 1;
    }
}
 console.log(p + ' valores positivos');
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenta usar o "filter" com "Math.sign"

```
var positivos = [7, -5, 6, -3.4, 4.6, 12].filter(x => Math.sign(x) == 0 || Math.sign(x) == 1);
    // positivos fica sendo [7, 6, 4.6, 12]
```

[filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro)

[Math.sign](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sign)